# SHorting MIPI Mux lines

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, multiplexer, csi

I am currenty using the TS5MP646 http://www.ti.com/product/TS5MP646 . I need to build a 4:1 mux. I was wondering if I need to use 3 muxes, or can i just short the MIPI traces together and control it using OE pin on the mux?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the top of page 18 of the datasheet, you’ll see that /OE set high sets all the I/O pins to high-Z. Therefore, yes, at least in theory, you can wire-OR the outputs. Depending on the speed of the signals, you may have an issue with reflections from the stubs.

Comment: Would you recommend a 2 level design?